# Angular 2 John Papas' Seed Project with simple Apache Server

Tags: angular, angular-seed

Does anyone know a **github repo** with a simple **Angular 2 Seed Project** following all the concepts of John Papas [Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)?

All the other seeds I have found does not follows the style guide properly.

Comment: The Angular2 CLI follows the style guide AFAIK: https://cli.angular.io
You can have a start project in a minute or less with this

Comment: @LDJ I thanks I didn't know this client for angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try this repo? This may be helpful!

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes

Comment: Got it ! it seams exactly what I want! thanks for the tip